# UIView animate with few objects

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want this elements make animation one by one in a line with duration, but instead the are making animation together in the same moment

```
            authClicked = true
            var angle: CGFloat = 45.0

            google = UIButton(type: .custom)
            facebook = UIButton(type: .custom)
            vk = UIButton(type: .custom)
            instagram = UIButton(type: .custom)
            regular = UIButton(type: .custom)

            let buttonArray = [self.google: "Google", self.facebook: "Facebook", self.vk: "VK", self.instagram: "Instagram", self.regular: "Regular"];

            for (button, buttonName) in buttonArray {
                button.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 150, height: 150)
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
                button.setTitle(buttonName, for: .normal)
                button.alpha = 0

                circleButton(button: button)

                angle -= 45.0
                view.addSubview(button)

                let cosX = cos(angle) * 200
                let sinY = sin(angle) * 200

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 1.0, options: [], animations: {
                    button.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: cosX, y: sinY).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5))
                    button.alpha = 1
                }) { (done) in
                    print(done)
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code, they are all being executed at the same time (after a delay of 1.0 seconds).

To change this:

```
// create a variable outside of the for loop
var animationDelayTime = 1.0

// the for loop
for (button, buttonName) in buttonArray {

            // the other stuff
            ... 
            ...
            ...


            // instead of 1.0 for delay, use animationDelayTime
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: animationDelayTime, options: [], animations: {
                button.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: cosX, y: sinY).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5))
                button.alpha = 1
            }) { (done) in
                print(done)
            }

    // after the animation is done, increment the var for the next iteration.
    // it will be 1.25 for the 2nd loop, then 1.50, then 1.75, etc.
    animationDelayTime += 0.25

} // end, for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

just Increase delay time, as for loop is fast and not taking time, each element is stating at the same time, So you need to give different delay for each animation to start. Create one variable animationDelay and pass it to the uiview.animaton

```
var animationDelay = 1.0 //your dealy for first element


for (button, buttonName) in buttonArray {
      button.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 150, height: 150)
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
      button.setTitle(buttonName, for: .normal)
      button.alpha = 0

      circleButton(button: button)

      angle -= 45.0
      view.addSubview(button)

      let cosX = cos(angle) * 200
      let sinY = sin(angle) * 200
      //set created animationDelay 
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: animationDelay, options: [], animations: {
          button.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: cosX, y: sinY).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5))
          button.alpha = 1
      }) { (done) in
          print(done)
      }
      animationDelay += 0.35 // increment the delay you want between each elemnts 
}
```